# How to create a internet link on my desktop?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there some API to create a link on my desktop that point to http://www.google.com ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#intshcut_creating_with_url

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not show, how to create shortcuts to URLs. It shows how to create shell shortcuts (.lnk files) only. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Agree; per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx) `IShellLink` " cannot be used to create a link to a URL."

Answer (score -1):

Never done that, but try this:

Manually create a link on your desktop. Give it a name, as well as the link itself.
Then navigate to your desktop directory, usually inside `c:\documents and settings\<user>\Desktop` and search for the link you entered. On my PC it's a .url file. Open that file and view its contents.

Then try to programmatically create such a file in the Desktop directory.
It's a hack but might work.